# How to compute the change-of-coordinates matrix from B to B' with 2x2 matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have

$$B=([1,1], [1,0])$$

$$B'=([0,1],[1,1])$$

and I need to find the change-of-coordinates from B to B'. I have performed the following steps:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 | \ 1 & 1\\ 
1 & 1 | \ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 | \ 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 | \ 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 | \ 0 & -1\\ 
0 & 1 | \ 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then,

$$
C_{B,B'}=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & -1\\ 
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Is my procedure correct?